# Unit test, should i modify method parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm working on a nasty legacy project at the moment and I'd be glad to add unit tests to whatever I fix.

```
public abstract class AbstractYYY extends XX {

   private LoginDTO selectedLogin;
   private Tab tab;
   private GenericJobDTO job;



   @Override
   public void action() throws TabException {
     JobContainerDTO jobContainer = tab.getRoot().getData();

     jobContainer.setUser(tab.getUsername());
     jobContainer.setServer(tab.getConnectorURL());
     jobContainer.setPlatform(tab.getPlatform());
     jobContainer.setLoginID(selectedLogin.getId());

     if (jobContainer.getApp().equals(App.TEST)) {
        if (job instanceof JobDTO) {
            ((JobDTO) job).setLoginId(selectedLogin.getId());
            ((JobDTO) job).setZoneId(jobContainer.getZoneId());
        }

        if (job instanceof JobAutoDTO) {
            ((JobAutoDTO) job).setLogin(selectedLogin.getId());
            if(selectedLogin.getConnector() != null ){
                ((JobAutoDTO) job).setConnectorId(selectedLogin.getConnector().getId());
            }
        }
     }


     if (jobContainer.getStatus() != 1 ) {
        jobContainer.setLastRunStartTime(0);
        jobContainer.setLastRunEndTime(0);
        jobContainer.setLog("");
     }

     job.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
     jobContainer.setJobXYZasJSON(job.toJson());
     jobContainer.setWorker(job.getWorker());
     jobContainer.setId(savedID);


     if (jobController != null) {
        jobController.action();
     }

 }

.
.
.
.

}
```

I'd like to test how my `jobContainer` is filled, so I created a method like

JobContainerDTO setContainerInfo(JobContainerDTO jobContainer, Tab tab...)

But it means I'll have to modify the parameter `jobContainer`, which does not seem like a good idea.

How would you test this method ?

Comment: do you want to test all from the action method or certain part? which part?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to be able to write smaller method that filled my jobContainer and the job. and then be able to test the action method as well

Comment: are tab, selectedLogin, savedID .. instance variables?

Comment: yes they are, and they are modified by other methods in this class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create two helper classes.

One for filling the jobContainer and other specializing in the filling of the job.

**JobContainerResolver**

```
public class JobContainerResolver{

   private JobContainer jobContainer;

   public JobContainerResolver(JobContainer jobContainer){
        this.jobContainer = jobContainer;
   }

   public void fillWithTabData(Tab tab){
        jobContainer.setUser(tab.getUsername());
        jobContainer.setServer(tab.getConnectorURL());
        jobContainer.setPlatform(tab.getPlatform());
   }

   public void fillWithJobData(Job job){
       jobContainer.setJobXYZasJSON(job.toJson());
       jobContainer.setWorker(job.getWorker());
   }

   public void fillWithIds(SelectedLogin login, Integer savedID){
        jobContainer.setId(savedID);
        jobContainer.setLoginID(selectedLogin.getId());
   }

}
```

**JobResolver**

```
public class JobResolver{

    private Job job;

    public JobResolver(Job job){
         this.job = job;
    }   

    public fillWithBasicData(JobContainer, SelectedLogin){
        if (jobContainer.getApp().equals(App.TEST)) {
           if (job instanceof JobDTO) {
             ((JobDTO) job).setLoginId(selectedLogin.getId());
             ((JobDTO) job).setZoneId(jobContainer.getZoneId());
           }

           if (job instanceof JobAutoDTO) {
             ((JobAutoDTO) job).setLogin(selectedLogin.getId());
             if(selectedLogin.getConnector() != null ){
                   ((JobAutoDTO) job).setConnectorId(selectedLogin.getConnector().getId());
             }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

**action() method**

```
@Override
public void action() throws TabException {
    JobContainerDTO jobContainer = tab.getRoot().getData();

    JobContainerResolver jcResolver = buildJobContainerResolver(jobContainer);

    JobResolver jResolver = buildJobResolver(job);

    jcResolver.fillWithTabData(tab); 
    jcResolver.fillWithJobData(job);
    jcResolver.fillWithIds(selectedLogin, savedID);

    jResolver.fillWithBasicData(jobContainer, selectedLogin);
}

public JobContainerResolver buildJobContainerResolver(JobContainer jc){
    return new JobContainerResolver(jc);
}

public JobResolver buildJobResolver(Job job){
    return new JobResolver(job);
}
```

With this structure, you can test in isolation different settings and the action() method itself. You just need to play with mocking a bit.

Comment: I appreciate this way of doing, I wanted to do something like that but I thought I had to pass the jobContainer instance to my method and so change my method parameter. 
But you're way of doing is better I think.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to add a clone method to jobContainer and have no side effect at all ?

Answer (score 1):

You can mock your `Tab tab` field so it will return an object that you can assert.

```
@Mock
private Tab tab;

@InjectMocks
private AbstractYYY testClass = new RealYYY;

@Test
public void test(){
    JobContainerDTO jobContainer = new JobContainerDTO();
    Root mockedRoot = mock(Root.class);
    when(tab.getRoot).thenReturn(mockedRoot);
    when(mockedRoot.getData()).thenReturn(jobContainer);

    testClass.action();

   //Here you can assert that JobContainerDTO jobContainer is in the state that you expect it to be.
}
```

The same approach can be done with `GenericJobDTO job`. You need to mock it, and then verify method calls.